# Add filter to PivotTable

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, filter, pivot-table

I have created pivot table in my script. Suppose this pivot table is named **pivotTable**. I would like to add a filter to this table, so I use **FilterCriteria** class to achieve this.

I can do something like this:

```
pivotTable.addFilter(colNumber, SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().setVisibleValues(["dog", "cat"]).build());
```

After executing this function, in **pivotTable** remain only rows which in the column with index **colNumber** have the value "cat" or "dog". Now I want to do something like that:

```
pivotTable.addFilter(anotherColNumber, SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenCellNotEmpty().build());
```

...and then I get exception:

```
Exception: The pivot table filter criteria should only contain visible values.
```

My problem is that:

- I do not understand the exception I receive (what exactly means "visible values"?).
- I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
- I can't find the answer to this or similar problem.
- Most of answers, which I find, relate to javascript, so they don't help me.
- There is no examples in documentation https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What happens if you do `pivotTable.addFilter(anotherColNumber, SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenCellNotEmpty().build());` first?

Comment: If I change criteria order, the error is the same. Even if I have only one criteria `whenCellNotEmpty()`  , I get the same exception.

Comment: *what exactly means "visible values* It probably means you can only `.setVisibleValues()` as filter criteria. Can you manually set other filter criteria in Google sheets?

Comment: @TheMaster Yes, I can set this or other criteria manually. It will be strange If I couldn't do it with a script, so I think I make some mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, At present, It seems "Filter By Condition" in the pivot table cannot be manipulated programmatically. Only "Filter By Values" can be manipulated using [`setVisibleValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter-criteria-builder#setVisibleValues(String)).Consider <strike>creating a [issue in the issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=823905)</strike> adding a star (★ on top left) to this [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/166291466) created by [Fi Teach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60919232/add-filter-to-pivottable/60948734?noredirect=1#comment112454889_60948734)

Comment: Thanks for calrifying, i also got the same issue to match the filter criterion
.whentextcontains
I have created the issue on issue tracker here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/166291466